# Get param value dynamically

Tags: ruby, parameters

My question model holds the prompt and the answer choices for questions that students can answer. It includes columns named :choice_0, :choice_1, :choice_2, :choice_3, :choice_4, and :choice_5.

In one section of my controller, I've used the following code:

```
correct_array.push(these_params[:choice_0]) if !these_params[:choice_0].blank?
correct_array.push(these_params[:choice_1]) if !these_params[:choice_1].blank?
correct_array.push(these_params[:choice_2]) if !these_params[:choice_2].blank?
correct_array.push(these_params[:choice_3]) if !these_params[:choice_3].blank?
correct_array.push(these_params[:choice_4]) if !these_params[:choice_4].blank?
correct_array.push(these_params[:choice_5]) if !these_params[:choice_5].blank?
```

In other areas of my app, I've used the #{} syntax, for example:

```
params[:choice_#{n}]
```

But that doesn't work within a params hash for some reason. I'm sure that there is a drier way to accomplish these five lines.

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: You can use `params["choice_#{n}".to_sym]`

Comment: Aha! It needs to be converted to a symbol!

Comment: or you can create it as a symbol: `params[:"choice_#{n}"]`

Comment: @JeffZivkovic is this a Rails question?

Comment: @Stefan, it has no specific context for rails, so no this is purely Ruby

Comment: Thanks for the extra comment, @TheChamp. I actually prefer the syntax you've suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more Ruby way to do this is:

```
correct_array = (0..5).map { |i| these_params["choice_#{i}".to_sym] }.select(&:present?)
```

Or as a method:

```
def correct_array
  (0..5).map { |i| these_params["choice_#{i}".to_sym] }.select(&:present?)
end
```

In either case, you have the added bonus of not having to initialize `correct_array` as it is created on the fly.

Comment: Even more awesome. Stuff like this is what I love about Ruby. In my controller, however, I think that I still need to initialize the correct_array because this syntax occurs within a "when" branch of a "case tree". It populates the correct_array this way when the style of the question is "fill-in", but populates correct_array a different way when the style is "multiple-choice". At the end of the case tree it updates the model using @question.update(:correct_answers => correct_array). Although there is probably be some more Ruby magic that I'm not yet aware of.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
(0..5).each do |i|
  param_i = these_params["choice_#{i}".to_sym]
  correct_array.push(param_i) if param_i.present?
end
```